# Do Visa and MasterCard process exchange differently?

Tags: credit-card, foreign-exchange

My friend, who is willing to visit Indonesia, went to a Russian bank to get a debit card.

The manager advised him to go with MasterCard rather than Visa, because "Visa would first convert rubles to U.S. dollars then to rupiahs, and MasterCard would do a direct exchange".

This is not what I heard about how the cards work, still, that's what a bank person says.

Is there something behind this statement?

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10293/is-there-any-inherent-difference-between-visa-and-mastercard-credit-cards/26737#26737 Your answer

Comment: I don't believe either converts to roubles directly. Visa always uses USD, MC can chose between EUR and USD (as explained in the linked answer).

Answer (score 4):

#### In this case, the Visa/MC conversion process difference doesn't actually matter.

As noted by [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/36650/14835), both Visa and MasterCard use exchange rates that will get you equivalent exchanges regardless of how many currencies the exchange goes through.

e.g. It doesn't matter if you go `1 x 1.4` or if you go `1 x .5 x 2.8`, you're going to end up with the same thing at the end. They don't charge a markup for each leg of the conversion, in this case.